# What is the purpose of the extra remote branch to the original repo in my forked repository?

Tags: git, github

I recently forked the repo ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings.git and cloned to my desktop. I then set my upstream branches to point to this repo.

However, when I type `git remote -v` I see and extra repository in there (ZoomerAnalytics). What is this branch for? It doesn't seem like a normal branch and I am wary of deleting it. However, it's also not acting like an upstream remote either. Below is the output

```
$ git remote -v
ZoomerAnalytics https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings.git (fetch)
ZoomerAnalytics https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings.git (push)
origin  https://github.com/Eupraxis/xlwings.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/Eupraxis/xlwings.git (push)
upstream        https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings.git (fetch)
upstream        https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings.git (push)
```

What are the following remotes for?

```
ZoomerAnalytics https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings.git (fetch)
ZoomerAnalytics https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings.git (push)
```

Comment: None of those are *branches*; they're all remotes. I have no idea what it's intended for: "intent" implies something on the part of who- or what-ever created it. A remote is simply a name with at least one URL (each of these has just one URL, you just see it twice because `git remote` prints both the fetch and push variants, which are the same if there's only the one URL) that also acts as a base string for *remote-tracking branches* once you run `git fetch`. Presumably, if you created `upstream`, you choose your own intent. If I had to guess, their intent is the same as your intent.

Comment: @torek I created the "upstream" remotes to allow me to sync my fork with the original repo (per instructions on git). However, is the use of "upstream" as a name for a remote just a convention? (In other words, could I just fetch directly from ZoomerAnalytics?) ...I'm a newb in GitHub, so I'm thinking this may be the case.

Comment: Indeed, it's just a convention. I'm not sure whose convention I prefer: obviously making the other fork the name of the upstream remote works as a reminder, but on the other hand, `upstream` is a whole lot easier to type!

Comment: @torek thanks...sometimes well-followed conventions can confuse us noobs (think "self" in Python...its NOT a keyword!) ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears from the comments by @torek that indeed the ZoomerAnalytics remotes play the role of "upstream" in the GitHub help instructions. Its just convention to name the originating repo "upstream".